# How to know the owner class of a object

Tags: c++

Is there any way to know who is the owner of the object?? Lets say class A holds the pointer of class B as a data member. Is there any way B can know who is owning him??

Any help would be really means a lot to me.

Comment: What if multiple objects hold pointers to the B instance?

Comment: If you want a class to know its "owner" (which can mean many things in different contexts), then you will have to pass a pointer to the owner to the class's constructor and store it.

Comment: There's no magic way to do this. If you want the concept of one object being owned by another you have to implement it in some code. The details of that would depend greatly on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth In my design only One object holds pointer to B.

Comment: Why do you want to know? What is the problem that you are trying to solve that requires you to understand this relationship.

Answer (score 6):

The concept of "ownership" is not built in to the C++ language. It's a design concept used by programmers to understand their own code, not a language feature. Usually it means some code entity that has responsibility for releasing a resource (such as a dynamically-allocated object), but sometimes it means something  different.

So there is no way in general for an object to determine its "ownership", because there is more than one way that the code using the object might define and manage ownership.

Depending on what ownership means in your program, `boost::enable_shared_from_this` might help you. It allows an object (or someone with a reference to it) to participate in shared ownership of that object, but it still doesn't tell you want other entities it is sharing with. So it's useful if you don't actually need to know about the instance of `A`, you just need the instance of `B` not to get released. `A`, and anyone else interested in the lifecycle of the instance of `B`, would all hold a `shared_ptr` to `B` that they acquired using the `shared_from_this` function.

If you need `B` to access the instance of `A` then you will have to create your own mechanism. For example, you could perhaps store a pointer to the instance of `A` in the instance of `B`.